# How to avoid calling onCreate method after incoming call or any other idea about this in android version 2.1?

Tags: android, phone-call

How to avoid calling onCreate method after **incoming call** or any other idea about this in android version 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an activity restarts, it bypasses onCreate() so you don't have worry about that.

*That's assuming of course that the Activity wasn't killed because of some lack of memory. Of course, if the process was killed, you'll have to reinitialize everything again anyway, so that's the behavior you'll want.*

Check out the Activity lifecyle again:
http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/app/doc-files/activity_lifecycle.png